# How to get last commit time of every user in a git repo?

Tags: git, git-log

There are many persons working on the same git repo. I'd like to list each person's last commit time. Like:

```
Alice Nov 22 
Bob Nov 21 
Charlie Nov 29
```

...

I know that I can get a specific person's last commit using:

```
git log --author="bob" -1
```

Is it possible to get everybody's last commit time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** First, you can build the authors' list by sorting the log with

```
git log --all --pretty=format:"%aN" | sort -u
```

At this point, let's note that you might want to use a [`.mailmap`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmailmap) to normalize your repo's possible multiple aliases for authors (or else `Joe Schmoe` will be considered a different author from `joeshmoe` and `joe.schmoe.home`, which are the other names of the same author but from different machines).

**(2)** Then just loop over the list with a `while`, and get the most recent commit for each one, like

```
git log --all --pretty=format:"%aN" | sort -u | while read -r line ; do git log --all --pretty="%aN %ad" --date=short -1 --author="$line"; done
```

...finally **(3)** since noone wants to have to type this long chain of commands each time, the almost mandatory alias could be

```
# set the alias
git config --global alias.autlog '!git log --all --pretty=format:"%aN" | sort -u | while read -r line ; do git log --all --pretty="%aN %ad" --date=short -1 --author="$line"; done'

# use it
git autlog
```

Comment: Thanks for the `while read -r line; do ... done;` part, this helps to loop the authors to get each commit time.